# C++ local variable syntax

Tags: c++, syntax, reference

I have a `map<int, vector<int>> M`. In some functions I want to use `M[someInt]` multiple times. Instead of having `M[someInt].size()`, `M[someInt].push_back(123)` etc all over the place I want to use a local variable instead.

I'm currently using `vector<int> v = M[someInt];` however I don't want to copy the contents of the vector. I think I can do `vector<int> *v = &M[someInt];`

**How can I create a local variable that refers to `M[someInt]` w/o copying the vector's contents and, ideally, w/o using a pointer?**

Comment: "a local variable that refers to `M[someInt]`" - like a reference?

Comment: In C++ this is what references are for.

Comment: `auto& v = M[someInt];`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do `vector<int>& v = M[someInt];`.